# Kotlin Flow vs Android LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have some questions about **Kotlin Flow**

1. I can observe `LiveData` from multiple Fragments. Can I do this with `Flow`? If yes then how?
2. We can have multiple `LiveData` from a single `LiveData` using `map`& `switchMap`. Is there any way to have multiple `Flow` from a single source `Flow`?
3. Using `MutableLiveData` I can update data from anywhere using the variable reference. Is there any way to do the same with `Flow`?

I have a use-case like: I will observe a `SharedPreferences` using `callbackFlow{...}` which will give me a single source Flow. From that Flow, I want to create multiple Flow for each key-value pair.

These might sound silly questions. I am new to Rx and Flow world.

Comment: Which approach did you settle on - **Flow** or **LiveData**?

Comment: Currently, I am using LiveData for views and Flow for everything others. In ViewModel, I receive Flow and emits LiveData to observe from fragments.

Comment: @zoha131 you do it in the right way ! Since LiveData can be observe only on main thread they fit perfectly to View<->ViewModel interactions. Then Flows let you make more complex operations in the rest of your architecture.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> I can observe LiveData from multiple Fragments. Can I do this with Flow? If yes then how?

Yes. You can do this with `emit` and `collect`. Think `emit` is similar to live data `postValue` and `collect` is similar to `observe`. Lets give an example.

**Repository**

```
// I just faked the weather forecast
val weatherForecast = listOf("10", "12", "9")

// This function returns flow of forecast data
// Whenever the data is fetched, it is emitted so that
// collector can collect (if there is any)
fun getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds(): Flow<String> = flow { 
    for (i in weatherForecast) {
        delay(2000)
        emit(i)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
fun getWeatherForecast(): Flow<String> {
    return forecastRepository.getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds()
}
```

**Fragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Collect is suspend function. So you have to call it from a 
    // coroutine scope. You can create a new coroutine or just use 
    // lifecycleScope
    // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines
    lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getWeatherForecast().collect {
                    // Use the weather forecast data
                    // This will be called 3 times since we have 3 
                    // weather forecast data
            }
    }
}
```

> We can have multiple LiveData from a single LiveData using map& switchMap. Is there any way to have multiple Flow from a single source Flow?

Flow is very handy. You can just create flow inside flow. Lets say you want to append degree sign to each of the weather forecast data.

**ViewModel**

```
fun getWeatherForecast(): Flow<String> {
    return flow {
        forecastRepository
            .getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds(spendingDetailsRequest)
                .map {
                    it + " °C"
                }
                .collect {
                    // This will send "10 °C", "12 °C" and "9 °C" respectively
                    emit(it) 
                }
    }
}
```

Then collect the data in Fragment same as #1. Here what happens is view model is collecting data from repository and fragment is collecting data from view model.

> Using MutableLiveData I can update data from anywhere using the variable reference. Is there any way to do the same with Flow?

You cant emit value outside of flow. The code block inside flow is only executed when there is any collector. But you can convert flow to live data by using asLiveData extension from LiveData.

**ViewModel**

```
fun getWeatherForecast(): LiveData<String> {
    return forecastRepository
    .getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds()
    .asLiveData() // Convert flow to live data
}
```

In your case you can do this

```
private fun getSharedPrefFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val sharedPref = context?.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPref?.all?.forEach {
        offer(it)
    }
}

getSharedPrefFlow().collect {
    val key = it.key
    val value = it.value
}
```

***Edit***

Thanks to @mark for his comment. Creating a new flow in the view model for `getWeatherForecast` function is actually unnecessary. It could be re-written as

```
fun getWeatherForecast(): Flow<String> {
        return forecastRepository
                .getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds(spendingDetailsRequest)
                    .map {
                        it + " °C"
                    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why but I had an assumption that I can't call collect () function in multiple places for a single Flow. thanks for the answer.

Comment: No. You can collect the same flow in multiple places. `val sharedPref = getSharedPref()`and you can use collect in multiple places `sharedPref.collect {}`. The only thing is because collect is suspend, you need to call it from coroutine block. And happy to help np :)

Comment: for my third question, the workaround might be a broadcast channel.

Comment: You can check this commit for using channels instead of live data. https://github.com/android/plaid/pull/770/commits/db56835ff370e5f6cc70d2af4a2f3a0d16eabd91

Comment: @Faith Google recommends staying away from Channels API unless `really necessary`

Comment: Yes you are right. This is where flow comes in. Channels have lots of things you have to take care of and they are hot meaning they are always open even if there is no observers. But with flow you can get the same benefits without any concerns because they are cold. So instead of channel I think it is better to use flow

Comment: There is `emit` api on LiveData as well as Flow?

Comment: There is emit api on liveData builder https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

Comment: In the second example, why are you collecting and emitting?  Why not just return the mapped flow?

Comment: Actually you are right. It could just return the flow itself after mapping. I will edit it. Thanks :)

Comment: In the `Fragment`, shouldn't it be `viewModel.getWeatherForecast().collect {...}` instead of `viewModel.getWeatherForecastEveryTwoSeconds().collect {...}`? The latter method doesn't exist in the view model.

Comment: How does it possible to emit data within Firebase listeners? `override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {` `override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {`

Comment: Great answer! But can you please explain why is Flow even required when we already have LiveData?  I'm new to Kotlin flow

Comment: Be aware that you should not collect directly after launch. Use `repeatOnLifecycle`

Comment: Does Flow work about the same as MutablieLiveData though? It seems it just has a few more features, which might be possible with MutablieLiveData yet take more code, no?

Answer (score 17):

There is a new `Flow.asLiveData()` extension function in the new `androidx.lifecycle` ktx packages. You can learn more in my article:
https://www.netguru.com/codestories/android-coroutines-%EF%B8%8Fin-2020

Comment: When do we need to use this?

Comment: When you want to satisfy an API which requires LiveData with a Flow instance

Comment: when you have room database, and you want to observe all changes happens inside your database, but because you are using clean architecture your repository shouldn't return live data -since it's platform related- as a clean solution your doa classes should return flow also your repository should return flow, then transform them into livedata as shown in the answer, make sure that the same doa instance is used for retrieving and updating data in order to get flow works properly

Comment: @Amr Is there any reason not to prefer `lifecycleScope.launch { flow.collect() { [...] } }` (except for the 'boilerplatiness') in order to avoid the additional dependency of using LiveData?

Comment: @FilipÖstermark In fact now all are replacing LiveData with Flow. Here is more info 
[techs are sunsetting LiveData is included](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/3-android-techs-that-are-sunsetting-in-2022-74f86fd8b571) ----------------
[Guy from google writes how to migrate from LiveData to Flow](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-livedata-to-kotlins-flow-379292f419fb)  
---------------- [Here how to collect flow normally](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)

Answer (score 16):

In a 3-tier architecture: data-domain-presentation, Flow should take place in the data layer (databases, network, cache...) and then as [Samuel Urbanowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379751/samuel-urbanowicz) mentioned you can map Flow to LiveData.

In general, Flow is almost what the Observable (or Flowable) is for RxJava. Don't confuse it with LiveData.

more here: https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9

Comment: For one-shot operations (i.e. Database read), LiveData is sufficient.

Comment: "Don't confuse it with LiveData."  How? I'm new to Kotin flow and so far I have understood that same functionality can be achieved using LiveData as well. Can you please explain in detail. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AsthaGarg as the documentation says  LiveData is a lifecycle-aware observable and it is mainly used between ViewModel and Fragments/Activities. Of course, you can use LiveData to get updates from for example databases, but for this reason, now you should use Flow. This page https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow explains it better than I can do. And keep in mind now the StateFlow/SharedFlow is the new LiveData

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add on to Fatih's answer here since it's been sometime.

> I can observe LiveData from multiple Fragments. Can I do this with Flow? If yes then how?

Yes. But the way you should do that has changed a bit. You should use `repeatOnLifecycle` to more safely post to the UI from Flows. It's new and the docs are scarce but this is what it looks like:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        viewModel.getWeatherForecast().collect {
           // Safely update the UI
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the weather forecast only updates the UI when it's showing and doesn't waste resources. And yes, you can do this on multiple Fragments from the same Flow at the same time.

> We can have multiple LiveData from a single LiveData using map& switchMap. Is there any way to have multiple Flow from a single source Flow?

This is an obvious yes. Flows have tons of operators [like map and switchMap](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/)

> Using MutableLiveData I can update data from anywhere using the variable reference. Is there any way to do the same with Flow?

Yes. We now have [MutableStateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) which is very close to and more powerful that `MutableLiveData`.

```
val textFlow = MutableStateFlow("Hello")

someButton.onPress {
    textFlow.value = "World"
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        textFlow.collect {
           someTextView.text = it
        }
    }
}
```

The SharedPreferences code above can be modified a bit:

```kotlin
private fun getSharedPrefFlow() = callbackFlow {
    val sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPref?.all?.forEach {
        trySend(it) // offer is deprecated
    }
}

init {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            getSharedPrefFlow()
                .filter { it.key == BIRTHDAY_KEY }
                .collect {
                    birthdayTextView.text = it.value
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding one more point,
LiveData is not built for asynchronous operations. All the transformation and work are in the main thread.

```
Presentation layer -> LiveData is enough
All other layers like Repository -> Use Kotlin flow
```

Comment: This seems like a key point that should've been covered in the discussion. Thanks for adding it. If async is needed a dev could write a lot of code before hitting problems.